# Show information about daily reputation cap on the reputation tab

Tags: feature-request, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-history

**TL;DR:** If the daily reputation cap is reached, on the reputation tab you can see upvotes that no longer increase reputation (or contribute less than the usual +5/+10). It might be useful to include somewhere on the reputation tab the information why this is the case. (Only if the daily reputation limit is reached - we do not want to add there too much redundant information that the users actually do not need.)

---

Often when users reach daily reputation cap and no longer get reputation from upvotes, they are confused why this is the case. Anyone who is sufficiently active on some per-site-meta have seen questions asking about this. It might be helpful to users if this information is shown somewhere on the reputation tab - this is the natural place where to look when somebody has a suspicion that something is off about their reputation changes. (Of course, this information is completely unnecessary if the user did not reach the limit - so it should only be displayed for days when it was actually reached.)

I am not exactly sure what would be the best way to achieve this. But perhaps the tooltip on upvotes on reputation tab which currently shows "answer was upvoted 1 time" or "question was upvoted 1 time" could include information about the reputation cap for the upvotes which no longer add reputation. (The screenshot below show how it is displayed at the moment.) Maybe a tooltip over some other part of the reputation tab would be a reasonable solution? Or perhaps somebody can think of better way how to include this information so that it would be visible. (I am not saying that it necessarily has to be a tooltip, but that seems like a solution that is not "too shouty".)

[image: Screenshot showing an example of reputation tab]

---

<sup>I decided to ask this after a recent question on Meta MathOverflow - [5 points for an upvote to an answer?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3912/5-points-for-an-upvote-to-an-answer) - and a [subsequent discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9369/conversation/information-about-daily-cap-not-shown-on-the-reputation-tab). (The example in the screenshot is also taken from this instance.) But I am pretty sure that questions about this appear on many per-site-metas - I have seen similar questions on the few sites that I frequent.</sup>

Comment: One of the functions of the Mortarboard badge is to make users aware of the rep cap.

Comment: @Glorfindel That is true and a very good point. On the other hand, many threads on meta about this can be considered an evidence that some people did not notice this or simply forget about the fact until they reach the limit the second time.

Comment: People who get confused and have to ask obviously don't read [the help pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 3):

An (additional?) idea would be to give the total reputation number a different color (also in the achievements inbox). Users will be a little bit confused about this (all the other totals are green, why is this one purple?) and a mouseover could show a popup with explanation and a link to the help center.

[image]

In addition to the different color, a border or a different background could be used to accommodate color-blind users.